# DB2 EJB/JPA does not rollback

Tags: java, jpa, jboss

I'm experimenting an very strange behaviour with CMT in JBoss6.1+ accessing zos/390 DB2.

Enviroment is:

- JBoss 6.1+
- Linux Red Hat
- DB2 running in ZOS 390
- EJB3/JPA2

Transaction simply does not rollback with SystemExceptions.
I tried BMT and surprisily does not works either.
My BMT code is bellow:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class ManterPortabilidadeBean
    implements PortabilidadeService {

    @Inject
    private UserTransaction tx;

    @Override
    public void incluirPortabilidade(...) {
        try {
        tx.begin();

            //insert into database          
        daoPortabilidade.incluir(portabilidade);

        if (1==1) 
            throw new EJBException("Bingo");

        tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            tx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        } 
    }
}
```

Well, the record is in database!!! Incredible!!!
EJB Container ignores completely, does nothing.

Here is CMT code:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class ManterPortabilidadeBean
    implements PortabilidadeService {

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void incluirPortabilidade(...) {
        //insert into database          
        daoPortabilidade.incluir(portabilidade);

        if (1==1) 
            throw new EJBException("Bingo");
    }
}
```

I believe that DB2 is commiting automatically, like autocommit=true, but configuration informes that autocommit is false, see persistence.xml bellow:

```
<persistence-unit name="gecDS" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/DB2SigecDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="GEC" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="2" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I standalone.xml I have this configuration for datasource:

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/DB2SigecDS" pool-name="jdbc/DB2SigecDS" enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:db2://************</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource</driver-class>
    <driver>db2</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>*******</user-name>
        <password>*******</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

Any idea, configuration???
Thx

Comment: Try to change the jta attribute to true in the datasource file.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the strange problem.
Just configurations!!!

In datasource attribute "jta" must be true (thx Aramburu), and I'm using XADatasource:

```
<persistence-unit name="gecDS" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/DB2SigecDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="GEC" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="2" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>


<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/DB2SigecDS" pool-name="jdbc/DB2SigecDS" enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:db2:**************</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource</driver-class>
    <driver>db2</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>???????</user-name>
        <password>???????</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

Thx friends